# Heroku app can't configure specific node modules/build-packages

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, discord.js

I am hosting a simple discord bot, all of its commands work besides commands associated with the *opus-script* and *ytdl* nodejs packages.

In my **package.json** i have the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.4.2",
    "dotenv-flow": "^0.2.0",
    "enmap": "^4.8.1",
    "opusscript": "0.0.7",
    "ytdl-core": "^0.29.5"
  }
```

I have tried using the heroku site gui to add each buildpack, which returns the following error when deployed:

**App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/esafirm/heroku-ytdl.git
       bash: /app/tmp/buildpacks/.../bin/detect: No such file or directory**

**App not compatible with buildpack: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/abalabahaha/opusscript
       bash: /app/tmp/buildpacks/.../bin/detect: No such file or directory**

- I have tried creating a folder called _node_modules_ in my github repository with the 2 packages, when deployed it manages to rebuild each package but the packages are never implemented into the bot.
- I have tested the bot localhost, so i know the commands are working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `node-opus` instead of `opusscript`, runs a lot faster. For good practice don't upload your node_modules to the repo and just do `npm i` when you `git pull --rebase` or `git pull` next time. As for the YTDL-core buildpack, take a look at [this](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/fent/node-ytdl-core#buildpack-instructions).